# visual studio 2012 crash after installing visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Recently I have downloaded Visual Studio 2013 ultimate, and I already had Visual Studio 2012 professional which was working fine.

However, after installing the VS2013, all of my VS2012 projects won't load. Even won't let me add any new files to the projects.

So, I captured the activity log by running the devenv.exe with `devenv.exe /log` command. An error was occur during opening up projects.

> ERROR Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same
>   ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop' is already loaded at
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON
>   FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK...
>             C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\   Extension Manager

Can anyone help me solving the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  The problem is caused by VS2013 installing two tools automatically that conflict with older version previously installed with VS2012. (sigh).  The two tools are:

- Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop
- Microsoft.WinJS

VS2012 installs version 8.0 and VS2013 installs version 8.1

**Solution**

1. Control Panel - Programs and Features
2. Select Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
3. Select Change
4. Select Modify
5. Unselect Tools for Maintaining Store Apps for Windows
   8 and Windows Phone 8.0 SDK
6. Save and restart either VS2012 or VS2013

If the error isn't gone, unselect anything having to do with developing Windows apps/programs and try again.